# React - member function is not a function when called in initial state (outside constructor)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react class with a member function that initializes the state:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  state = this.getInitialState(this.props)

  getInitialState = (props) => {
    // return some state based on props
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this.getInitialState is not a function
```

However if I have a constructor declared explicitly, then the component works fine

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = this.getInitialState(this.props)
  }

  getInitialState = (props) => {
    // return some state based on props
  }
}
```

Why does this happen?

EDIT: I am using create-react-app so babel should be configured to accept this syntax

Comment: do you have class properties enabled in your babel config? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Comment: Because the `state` variable is defined before your function

Comment: @WilomGfx I'm using create-react-app so I believe that is enabled by default

Comment: @Legend123 even i didn't think of this case, can't we call the method in componentWillMount which will be the first lifecycle method to call after the constructor and state. If you are using react 16 you don't need constructor and this.state

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS componentWillMount works but it feels hacky.

Comment: I think basically you need to understand the diff? Even if alternative methods are there

Answer (score 0):

[Made example with lifecycle getDerivedStaetFromProps](https://codepen.io/KoldunMax/pen/omMyWK)

```
    class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

 state = {}

 static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
   if (props.name !== state.newName) {
      return {
        newName: props.name+"value",
        newSurname: props.surname+"value"
      }
   }
   return null;
 }

  render () {
    return (
       <p>{this.state.newName} {this.state.newSurname}</p>
    )
  }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
   render () {
      return (
        <SomeComponent name="Nick" surname="Pin" />
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: I want the state to be set in the initial render but componentWillReceiveProps doesn't get called until a rerender happens. I could use componentDidMount but that feels hacky

Comment: tried make like that:
this.getInitialState  = this.getInitialState.bind(this) ?

Comment: Can you add some more detail as to how this works, and how the OP can integrate it with their code?  This will help future readers understand the answer, not just copy and paste. Thanks